# Effect size output of ANOVA obtained from anova_stats is different from effectsize::eta_squared

Tags: r, anova, effect-size

I ran an ANOVA using `aov` in R. Then I used both `effectsize::eta_squared` as well as `anova_stats` from the `sjstats` package to find the effect size. However, both are giving me a different value as shown in the screenshot below. The value in the output from `anova_stats` is almost half of the value that I get from `effectsize::eta_squared`. Which one is the actual effect size and why is there this difference? Which one to trust?

[image]